# Hide or group Typescript files in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, cordova, typescript, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I'm working in a cordova project using cordova tools for visual studio 2015.
I would like to hide the .js and .js.map files generated when compile the typescript files or maybe group the generated files under the .ts file.
Now when i save a ts file, the generated files keep in the same folder and makes it difficult to work.

Comment: If you are using the default Typescript template for Cordova, the generated js codes are injected into the same file "appBundle.js". Could you please post your `tsconfig.json`?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure what do you mean by "group". But if you want to exclude them from your view - changne in your user settings:

```
{
    "editor.fontSize": 15,
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.git": true,
        "**/.DS_Store": true,
        "**/*.map": true,
        "**/*.js": true


    },
"files.autoSave": "afterDelay"
}
```

Comment: I'm using Visual studio community 2015. I think you are talking about visual studio code.